# Анимация css заслоняет fixed блок над ним

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, не могу решить проблему. Создал `header` с позицией `fixed`, после него идет блок с анимацией. 
Если `header` занимает какую то часть блока с анимацией и она активирована, то анимация перекрывает `header`.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

файл **test.html**:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: 'stand';
  border-bottom: 1px black solid
}

.headerdown {
  margin-right: 6%;
  margin-left: 6%;
  width: 87%;
}

.header .headerdown table {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}

.header .headerdown table .stand {
  width: 18.5%;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px white solid;
  border-bottom: 1px white solid;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.header .headerdown table .Nstand {
  width: 26%;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px white solid;
  border-bottom: 1px white solid;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.menu {
  font-family: 'stand';
  float: right;
  width: 230px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.menu ul {
  font-size: 14pt;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menunews {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.menunews:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

.menunewstext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16pt;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.menunewstext a {
  color: black;
}

.menu li img,
.img {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

.menu li {}

.maincontent {
  font-family: 'stand';
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-right: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="headerdown">
    <div>

    </div>
    <div class="htable">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="stand"><a href="technologies.php">Технологии</a></td>
            <td class="stand"><a href="serialsfilms.php">Кино и Сериалы</a></td>
            <td class="stand"><a href="studybooks.php">Учеба и Книги</a></td>
            <td class="stand"><a href="health.php">Здоровье</a></td>
            <td class="Nstand"><a href="life.php">Повседневная жизнь</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <h2>Популярные статьи:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="menunews">
        <a href="">
          <div class="img"><img src=""></div>
          <div class="menunewstext"><a href="">Статья 1</a></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="maincontent">

</div>
```

Comment: Для начала выложите код который можно воспроизвести.

Comment: А где анимация?

Comment: Для этого существуют свойства `position` и `z-index`

Comment: Чтобы вопрос был решен,  надо код с проблемой вставлять, а не просто кусок, тут нет ни какой анимации и проблемы не видно, ну или же я слепой

Comment: Простите, не анимация, а transition, там в css файле: "transition: 0.6s linear;"